# How to extract first letter in grep in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract first letter in R using `grep`
How to do this?
This code extracts all of them

```
> grep( "*{1}", "siema", value= TRUE)
[1] "siema"
```

Comment: `grep` is for finding the pattern, you may need `sub` or `substr` for extracting

Comment: substr( "siema", 1,1) works fine. thanks

Comment: Or `strtrim('siema', 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, which is not a wrapper function like `stringr`, is the `stringi` package.

```
library("stringi")
stri_extract_first_regex("siema", ".{1}")
[1] "s"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
substr("siema",1,1)
```

Also I would recommend you take a look at the package stringr from hadley wickham. It helps a little with string operations.

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
str_sub("siema",1,1)
```

For this particular function it doesn't make much difference, however it makes string extraction much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
# no need for additional packages
sub("(.).*", "\\1", perl = TRUE, "siema")
```